# Malaysian visa spelling error

Tags: visas, malaysia

In my malaysian visa printed on my passport its showing 'P Emanuval Deepak ' instead of 'Panikulam Emanuval Deepak' it will cause any issue during the immigration?

Comment: You can check with the e visa chat support. They are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In general, Visa name should exactly match passport name. If its not the case, it can cause issue with boarding (Airline can deny boarding) or immigration.

You can confirm if its acceptable from the Malaysian e-visa support and keep a printed copy in case airline is not convinced.

Comment: I'd wager it's unlikely to cause problems.  Malaysia has a large Tamil minority and it's very common for them to abbreviate the first name (father's name) to an initial.

Comment: @jpatokal Indian passport doesn't accept abbreviated names. Although it cannot cause any issues usually, an overcautious (esp airline) staff can cause problems. Its better to confirm and carry the proof for peace of mind.